# Gradle: Using setIgnore on a local library based on the apps build.gradle flavor.

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

How do I use setIgnore on a local library either from the apps build.gradle or the library build.gradle based on the apps flavor. I am not sure if I can reference the apps build.gradle flavor/dimension from the library build.gradle. I also don't know if I can reference a library from the apps build.gradle and use lib.setIgnore(true). Any solution to solving this issue?

I am currently only using one dimension for the application and multiple flavors.

This is how it is typically done; but I need to set Ignore on a library based on the apps flavor.

```
android {
    ...
    variantFilter { variant ->
        if(variant.buildType.name == 'release' && variant.getFlavors().get(0).name == 'vanilla') {
            variant.setIgnore(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the library only when you need.

```
dependencies {
   // use "mylib" for debug
   debugImplementation project(path: ':mylib')
   // all the flavors
   implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am facing an issue when the library is not being used, that is why I am tryin to use setIgnore on the library

Comment: @EugeneH could you expand on the detail you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to wait for the task graph to be assembled and then removes the undesired name pattern as follows:

```
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { graph ->
  graph.allTasks.findAll { it.name ==~ /.*vanilla.*/ }*.enabled = false
}
```